# How to add custom claims for a Client-Server app in ADFS 2019?

Tags: adfs

How to add custom claims for an application group of type "Web browser accessing a web application - Client-Server application" in the provided token?

I'm building a web app using an Angular client and .NET Core Backend. I've managed to authenticate the client, but i can't use explicit authorization roles for controllers since the token doesn't provide those roles, e.g.

```cs
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you have to augment the id_token as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/custom-id-tokens-in-ad-fs).

But in order to do the "Roles=Admin", you have to have a claims rule that sends the groups as a claim type of "Role".

Comment: I've been searching the docs for a full day and couldn't find that one. Thanks!

Comment: I've ran into a different problem now. The custom claims are not visible on the server. If i check the ClaimsPrincipal for the current user, they are not there, but they can be seen if the token is parsed.

Comment: As far as i can tell, my `roles claim` is in the `access_token` and the server uses the `id_token_claims_obj` .

Comment: What do you mean by custom? What claims rules do you have?

Comment: I've managed to get it working! My `Authentication Scheme` config on the backend was the problem.